# comparing a complex api in a gridview builder to get a specific key

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am trying to get a specific id from this complex api:
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/data/en_US/champion.json
however everytime i try to get it from my code it gives the RangeError. i suspect this issue has to do with the index im using after my list but without the index it also shows an error that it isnt defined. im trying to compare the champion ID i get from my summonermastery class with the key i get from the champions class
code i was talking about:

```
image: NetworkImage('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/${ChampionList.data[index]?.name}.png'),
```

heres the rest of the code:
home_page.dart:

```
GridView.builder(
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20),
    itemCount: SummonerMasteryList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
      return ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
          leading: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border(
                    right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white24))),
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/${ChampionList.data[index]?.name}.png'),
                height: 75,
                width: 75,
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              SummonerMasteryList[index].championPoints.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(SummonerMasteryList[index].championId.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
          );
    }),
```

champion.dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Champions championsFromJson(String str) => Champions.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String championsToJson(Champions data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Champions {
  Champions({
    required this.type,
    required this.format,
    required this.version,
    required this.data,
  });

  Type? type;
  String format;
  Version? version;
  Map<String, Data> data;

  factory Champions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Champions(
    type: typeValues.map[json["type"]],
    format: json["format"],
    version: versionValues.map[json["version"]],
    data: Map.from(json["data"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Data>(k, Data.fromJson(v))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "type": typeValues.reverse?[type],
    "format": format,
    "version": versionValues.reverse?[version],
    "data": Map.from(data).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.version,
    required this.id,
    required this.key,
    required this.name,
    required this.title,
    required this.blurb,
    required this.info,
    required this.image,
    required this.tags,
    required this.partype,
    required this.stats,
  });

  Version? version;
  String id;
  String key;
  String name;
  String title;
  String blurb;
  Info info;
  ChampImage image;
  List<Tag> tags;
  String partype;
  Map<String, double> stats;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    version: versionValues.map[json["version"]],
    id: json["id"],
    key: json["key"],
    name: json["name"],
    title: json["title"],
    blurb: json["blurb"],
    info: Info.fromJson(json["info"]),
    image: ChampImage.fromJson(json["image"]),
    tags: List<Tag>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => tagValues.map[x])),
    partype: json["partype"],
    stats: Map.from(json["stats"]).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, double>(k, v.toDouble())),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "version": versionValues.reverse?[version],
    "id": id,
    "key": key,
    "name": name,
    "title": title,
    "blurb": blurb,
    "info": info.toJson(),
    "image": image.toJson(),
    "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => tagValues.reverse?[x])),
    "partype": partype,
    "stats": Map.from(stats).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v)),
  };
}

class ChampImage {
  ChampImage({
    required this.full,
    required this.sprite,
    required this.group,
    required this.x,
    required this.y,
    required this.w,
    required this.h,
  });

  String full;
  Sprite? sprite;
  Type? group;
  int x;
  int y;
  int w;
  int h;

  factory ChampImage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChampImage(
    full: json["full"],
    sprite: spriteValues.map[json["sprite"]],
    group: typeValues.map[json["group"]],
    x: json["x"],
    y: json["y"],
    w: json["w"],
    h: json["h"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "full": full,
    "sprite": spriteValues.reverse?[sprite],
    "group": typeValues.reverse?[group],
    "x": x,
    "y": y,
    "w": w,
    "h": h,
  };
}

enum Type { CHAMPION }

final typeValues = EnumValues({
  "champion": Type.CHAMPION
});

enum Sprite { CHAMPION0_PNG, CHAMPION1_PNG, CHAMPION2_PNG, CHAMPION3_PNG, CHAMPION4_PNG, CHAMPION5_PNG }

final spriteValues = EnumValues({
  "champion0.png": Sprite.CHAMPION0_PNG,
  "champion1.png": Sprite.CHAMPION1_PNG,
  "champion2.png": Sprite.CHAMPION2_PNG,
  "champion3.png": Sprite.CHAMPION3_PNG,
  "champion4.png": Sprite.CHAMPION4_PNG,
  "champion5.png": Sprite.CHAMPION5_PNG
});

class Info {
  Info({
    required this.attack,
    required this.defense,
    required this.magic,
    required this.difficulty,
  });

  int attack;
  int defense;
  int magic;
  int difficulty;

  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Info(
    attack: json["attack"],
    defense: json["defense"],
    magic: json["magic"],
    difficulty: json["difficulty"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "attack": attack,
    "defense": defense,
    "magic": magic,
    "difficulty": difficulty,
  };
}

enum Tag { FIGHTER, TANK, MAGE, ASSASSIN, MARKSMAN, SUPPORT }

final tagValues = EnumValues({
  "Assassin": Tag.ASSASSIN,
  "Fighter": Tag.FIGHTER,
  "Mage": Tag.MAGE,
  "Marksman": Tag.MARKSMAN,
  "Support": Tag.SUPPORT,
  "Tank": Tag.TANK
});

enum Version { THE_12221 }

final versionValues = EnumValues({
  "12.22.1": Version.THE_12221
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String>? get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
```

remoteservice.dart:

```
class ChampionById {
  static Future getAllChampions() {
    String link = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/data/en_US/champion.json';
    return http.get(Uri.parse(link));
  }
}
```

and here is my summoner.dart if its needed:

```
class SummonerMastery {
  int championId;
  int championLevel;
  int championPoints;
  int lastPlayTime;
  int championPointsSinceLastLevel;
  int championPointsUntilNextLevel;
  bool chestGranted;
  int tokensEarned;
  String summonerId;

  SummonerMastery.fromJson(Map json)
    : championId = json["championId"],
      championLevel = json["championLevel"],
      championPoints = json["championPoints"],
      lastPlayTime = json["lastPlayTime"],
      championPointsSinceLastLevel = json["championPointsSinceLastLevel"],
      championPointsUntilNextLevel = json["championPointsUntilNextLevel"],
      chestGranted = json["chestGranted"],
      tokensEarned = json["tokensEarned"],
      summonerId = json["summonerId"];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'championId': championId, 'championLevel': championLevel, 'championPoints': championPoints, 'lastPlayTime': lastPlayTime,
      'championPointsSinceLastLevel': championPointsSinceLastLevel, 'championPointsUntilNextLevel': championPointsUntilNextLevel,
      'chestGranted': chestGranted, 'tokensEarned': tokensEarned, 'summonerId': summonerId};
  }
}
```

tried a function which did not workout furthermore tried searching up any other methods but i just dont know how to search for it.

Comment: you want search in ChampionList and if an item's id in ChampionList is equal to item's id in SummonerMasteryList use it to show image?

Comment: Yes i want to search in my champion list for an key that is identical to the id of my SummonerMasteryList to use this to show an image and text from the championlist

Answer (score 0):

Change your GridView's builder to this:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
            Data? champ;
            for (var item in SummonerMasteryList) {
               for (var champion in ChampionList) {
                  champ = champion.data.values.toList().firstWhere((e) => e.key == item.championId.toString());
                  break;
               }
            }
            return ListTile(
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                leading: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      border: new Border(
                          right: new BorderSide(
                              width: 1.0, color: Colors.white24))),
                  child: Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/${champ?.name}.png'),
                    height: 75,
                    width: 75,
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  SummonerMasteryList[index].championPoints.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                    SummonerMasteryList[index].championId.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)));
          }
```

Comment: i get some errors with this first one:
```var champ = ChampionList.firstWhere((element) => element.data.key == SummonerMasteryList[index].championId);``` The getter 'key' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, Data> and the second one
```'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/img/profileicon/${champ?.name}.png')'```
The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'Champions'

Comment: so i put the ```${champ?.name}``` in a text and it just returns null

Comment: the SummonerMasteryList's item's id should be equal to ChampionList's item's data's id or key? because data have id and key, you look for which one?

Comment: also SummonerMastery has two id: summonerId, championId, you looking for which one?

Comment: i tried a debugprint and it logged this for champions list:
```ChampionList: []``` and this for summonermasterylist ```SummonerMasteryList: [Instance of 'SummonerMastery', Instance of 'SummonerMastery',``` this process repeats a few times... but i think championlist is not even getting any information at all

Comment: im looking for the championid, so the ChampionID and the Key should be identical to get the champ name

Comment: I updated my answer, but remember ChampionID is int but data's key is string.

Comment: @moosiker was it what you want?

Comment: sadly i think the api call still isnt getting any information for some reason since it still returns null

Comment: can you show me the code you call getAllChampions?

Comment: ```class ChampionById {
  static Future getAllChampions() {
    String link = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/12.22.1/data/en_US/champion.json';
    return http.get(Uri.parse(link));
  }
}``` here it is

Comment: no, I mean where you used it.

Comment: sorry bout that, here it is  ```void getAllChampionsFromApi() async {
    ChampionById.getAllChampions().then((response) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
        ChampionList = list.map((model) => Champions.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
    });
  }```

Comment: ```List<Champions> ChampionList = <Champions>[];```
This is the list btw